# ManyToMany relation and naming of columns in two variants

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

The user has two mapping of the list of invitations to friends

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_invitations",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_invited_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        }
)
private List<UserEntity> sentInvitations;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "users_invitations",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_invited_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        }
)
private List<UserEntity> receivedInvitations;
```

The first list is invitations sent, and the second list for invitations received. The difference lies in the naming of the column `joinColumns`, so that the first letter will be invitations sent from the user and the second invitation sent to the user. Unfortunately, it can not be compiled because it is thrown away

```
[EL Warning]: 2017-12-14 23:52:04.361--UnitOfWork(1221584693)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: t0.user_invited_id column does not exist
  Pozycja: 243
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t1.ID, t1.activation_token, t1.EMAIL, t1.email_change_token, t1.ENABLED, t1.modified_date, t1.new_email, t1.PASSWORD, t1.registration_date, t1.USERNAME, t1.UUID FROM users_invitations t0, users t1 WHERE ((t0.user_id = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.user_invited_id))
bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="sentInvitations" referenceClass=UserEntity sql="SELECT t1.ID, t1.activation_token, t1.EMAIL, t1.email_change_token, t1.ENABLED, t1.modified_date, t1.new_email, t1.PASSWORD, t1.registration_date, t1.USERNAME, t1.UUID FROM users_invitations t0, users t1 WHERE ((t0.user_id = ?) AND (t1.ID = t0.user_invited_id))")

ERROR: t0.user_invited_id column does not exist
```

The exception states that the column does not exist. How to fix it?

Comment: What does `UserEntity.java` look like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/si1trM3c

Answer (score 1):

The name value (here "users_invitations") in both the @ManyToMany is same.

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(
        name = "users_invitations",
```

Name Values should be different.